# Area under peaks considering mixture of normal distributions

Tags: r, normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I have a question regarding fitting mixture of normal distribution.
I have the following data:
[image]

I identified three peaks and using `mixtools` package, I fitted mixture of normal distributions to my data as follow:

```
mixture <- mixtools::normalmixEM(data, k = 3)
```

Consequently, I got 3 $\mu$ , 3 $\sigma$, and 3 $\lambda$ values.

My question is now how should I calculate the area under the peaks corresponding to the estimated normal distribution.

i.e., I need the area under the new curves which are in blue, red and green.
But my question is that, how from the calculate $\mu$ and $\sigma$, I reach to these three curves that I can consequently calculate the area under them.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "area under the peaks"? If you integrate over the entire mixture density, you should of course get a result of 1, up to numerical inaccuracy.

Comment: I have the peaks, and I got the normal distribution which corresponds (or I can relate them) to each peak. Now, I want to fit back my data for each estimated mu and sigma, then calculate the area under the new curve for each peak. Is this now clear? or?

Comment: Well, each separate normal density will integrate to 1. And each one comes with a weight in the mixture. I'm still unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: Your question is unclear. As noted by @StephanKolassa, area under the pdf is always equal to 1 by definition. On another hand, if we take your question literally as "what is the area under the points", then the answer is: it's **zero**, since points have no area ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry) ).

Comment: I don't want the area under the PDF!

Comment: What I'm looking for is the deconvoluted area under the peaks!
When I get the mu and sigma, I want to know how I can map it to my data (graph) and then calculate the area under the curve

Comment: I updated the figure and text

Comment: @sbmm: instead of repeating the same request over and over, try to express your question in probabilistic terms. Given the mixture estimate$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \hat{\lambda}_i f(x;\hat{\mu}_i,\hat{\sigma}_i),$$which functions are you interested in and why?

Comment: I have the densities, f(x;μ^i,σ^i) without knowing X.
Now I need $\lambda$s

Comment: So are you saying you want to model your data with a mixture of three 'original peaks' (from some distribution) convolved with a shared convolution kernel (say a normal distribution with constant std. dev.) and you want to recover the parameters of your peaks in your original peak distribution before the convolution happened? It would be easier if you present more context on which actual problem you are trying to solve and what is your original data and what is the question you want to answer.

Comment: Disclaimer: This is a ** WILD** guess! Observe the curves in the OP's graph don't integrate to one. By "curve" perhaps the OP is *not* referring to a density, but rather, raw histogram counts, something like a frequency curve. Perhaps the OP wants to (1) fit a gaussian mixture model then (2) use the results to obtain 3 new frequency curves, each of which doesn't integrate to 1 but rather integrates up to the number of cells (or whatever it is) in it's respective category???

Comment: Another wild guess: the OP wants to figure the total area under all three curves, not counting overlapping areas multiple times. Basically integrate numerically across an x range, where the height of each slice is the max of the three densities. Maybe.

Comment: @Tim already answered my question.
Thanks for your effort to understand my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that mixture distribution $f$ is a weighted sum of it's component distributions $f_1,\dots,f_k$:

$$ f(x) = \lambda_1 f_1(x;\mu_1, \sigma_1) + \lambda_2 f_2(x;\mu_2, \sigma_2) + \dots + \lambda_k f_k(x;\mu_k, \sigma_k) $$

where $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1$. Since $f$ integrates to unity and each of $f_i$ integrates to unity, you need to take $\lambda_i$ fraction of each of them. So height of each of $f_i$ densities gets multiplied by $\lambda_i$.

Below you can find simulated example that illustrates it.

```r
set.seed(123)

N <- 1e5
mu <- c(2,4,6)
sigma <- rep(0.5, 3)
lambda <- (1:3)/6

dat <- c(
  rnorm(N*lambda[1], mu[1], sigma[1]),
  rnorm(N*lambda[2], mu[2], sigma[2]),
  rnorm(N*lambda[3], mu[3], sigma[3])
)

xx <- seq(0, 8, by = 0.01)
hist(dat, 100, freq = FALSE, col = "lightgray", border = 1, xlab = "", main = "")
lines(xx, lambda[1]*dnorm(xx, mu[1], sigma[1]), col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(xx, lambda[2]*dnorm(xx, mu[2], sigma[2]), col = "blue", lwd = 2)
lines(xx, lambda[3]*dnorm(xx, mu[3], sigma[3]), col = "orange", lwd = 2)
```

[image: Individual densities in the mixture distribution]

`normalmixEM` function correctly identifies the parameters:

```r
summary(mixtools::normalmixEM(dat, k = 3))
## summary of normalmixEM object:
##          comp 1   comp 2   comp 3
## lambda 0.166202 0.334826 0.498973
## mu     1.998120 3.999630 6.004135
## sigma  0.498775 0.504762 0.497422
## loglik at estimate:  -165967.4
```

As about your second question in the comments, if your data is only `fy` points (density estimates) and corresponding `y` values, then the easiest way to estimate underlying model would be to create simulated dataset by sampling `y` values with probabilities proportional to `fy` and then use it for estimating your model as usual. Below you can see plot showing the kind of data that you describes and code example illustrating how to obtain the results.

[image]

```r
yy <- sample(y, 5000, prob = fy, replace = TRUE)
summary(mixtools::normalmixEM(yy, k = 3))
## number of iterations= 106 
## summary of normalmixEM object:
##          comp 1   comp 2   comp 3
## lambda 0.168503 0.324642 0.506855
## mu     1.973119 3.980462 5.976660
## sigma  0.471415 0.496197 0.527898
## loglik at estimate:  -8360.809
```

As you can see, with sample of just 25 pairs of `y`,`fy` values we were able to find the parameter values (notice that they are presented in different order then in the first example).

Comment: I need the new curves, or deconvoluted curves for which I have the new means and sigmas. I don't want the PDF curve.

Comment: @sbmm *what* new curves? Each individual curve is simply normal multiplied be $\lambda_i$...

Comment: the new deconvoluted curves you see in my figure.

Comment: @sbmm but those curves are just normal densities...

Comment: how should I then relate the $\lambda$s to the peaks?

Comment: @sbmm $\lambda_i$ are not related to peaks, peaks are marked by $\mu_i$'s, as with normal distribution that has mode=mean=median. Height of the peaks is height of normal densities at $\mu_i$ multiplied by $\lambda_i$

Comment: would it be possible to find mixture of normal distribution from density data? If I'm already given the density data, is there any function that I can use to find mixture of normal distributions?

Comment: @sbmm what do you mean by "density data"?

Comment: I have f(x) and don't know the $X$s. but normalmixEM can be only applied to $X$.

Comment: @sbmm check my edit for answer to your second question

Answer (score 2):

While I never looked into this I suppose it's simply the corresponding normalized $\lambda$.

---

Consider the following example, two normals, really far apart.

```
d = c(rnorm(n = 1000, mean = -10, sd = 0.5),
  rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10, sd = 0.5))
library(mixtools)
mixture = mixtools::normalmixEM(d, k = 2L)
plot(mixture, density = TRUE)
```

Here's the plot

[image: Two normals]

```
#> mixture$lambda
#[1] 0.5 0.5
```

Just what we'd expect the areas to be.

Comment: but the $\lambda$ s are also related to PDF curve, or?

Comment: I need the new curves, or deconvoluted curves for which I have the new means and sigmas.

Comment: @sbmm I edited the answer, please  tell me if that's what you meant as area under peaks.

Comment: but this is the density curve.
1- I need to deconvolute my curve
2- To do this, I fitted the mixture of normal distribution to obtain mean and standard deviation.
3- I want to take the mean and sd to transform my data and split my data into 3 curves.
4- for each curve calculate the area
Is this now more clear?

Comment: @sbmm $\lambda$ is the area, just like I pointed in my answer.

Comment: then how should I relate each $lamba$ to each peak?

Comment: @sbmm each lambda is the area of the respective curve.

Answer (score 0):

The area is one.  However, I think you mean how to find the probability of such interval [a,b] under each density.  If, yes you need to work with them separately.

Comment: I need the new curves, or deconvoluted curves for which I have the new means and sigmas estimated by mixtools. Then I can calculate the area under the curves.

Comment: @sbmm the area under the curves are, obviously, $\lambda$